# Position pattern matching

Tags: regex

I want to look through a list of words and find any that match the pattern of ABCCDAA. How can I do this? That is, find any words of length 7 whose letters correspond to that pattern (first and last two letters are X, etc).

Comment: Can you give an example of a pattern and a few words that you do/don't want to match it?

Comment: I did it! ([a-zA-Z]).([a-zA-Z])\2.\1\1

Comment: Fyi, you cannot do something like that with classic regular expressions - but luckily current regex engines are way more powerful than the "regular expressions" from theoretical computer science.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - backreferences (which is the only non-classical feature used in my answer) don't add any expressive power, you could still do this with a classical regex or DFA, but the regex would be hundereds of characters long - you would have to enumerate each of the possible As and Cs as separate branches - i.e. it would be `(a[a-z](aa|bb|cc|dd| ...)[a-z]aa|b[a-z](aa|bb|cc|...)bb|...)` very very long and frustrating

Comment: @ThiefMaster - taken to the extreme, this is in fact a finite language (finite number of strings match) so it can always be represented as a classical regex - just list each of the possibilities as alternatives. even seemingly context free languages which are restricted to make them finite can be made regular in this way e.g. all possible strings of at most `n` pairs of matched braces if `n` is 2 is something like `^(|{}|{}{}|{{}})$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
([a-zA-Z]).([a-zA-Z])\2.\1\1
```

Answer (score 1):

regex is simple enough -

```
/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])\3([a-zA-Z])\1\1$/
```